# What is the distribution of Saving Throws associated with each attribute that are required by spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, saving-throw

I read somewhere that in D&D 5e, the Saving Throw distribution for spells was biased towards **DEX**, **CON** and **WIS**. In other words, if you had proficiency in those attributes, you would benefit a lot more than having proficiency in other attributes.

**What is the distribution of Saving Throws across attributes for spells in D&D 5e?**

I'm looking for a percentage of each attribute for all the spells available (one would expect this to be uniform). Bonus points if this is also calculated for only spells that can be cast by RAW monsters (MM and VMG).

Comment: Note that every PC has proficiency with one of Dex, Con, and Wis and one of the remaining three, so "if you had proficiency in those attributes, you would benefit a lot more than having proficiency in other attributes" may be a redundant motivation for the question.

Comment: @Bloodcinder I think it's intended to say that if you have proficiency in more than one of those listed you would benefit more than not having it, but then even that's a tautologism.

Comment: @nitsua60 I've opened a Meta discussion here: [Is asking about the distribution of saving throws across all books too broad for this site?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6959/is-asking-about-the-distribution-of-saving-throws-across-all-books-too-broad-for)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In a similar format to the previous answer, here's an updated count of spells with saving throws available on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells). I've updated it again - it's now current as of 12 January 2024.

I am aware of two spells which don't list a primary save, but which can provoke a number of different saves:

- *[Symbol](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol)* (from the PHB and Basic Rules; thanks mdrichey in the comments for this one) has eight possible effects, each provoking a save, and the caster can choose which they want. I've effectively counted it as eight different spells, adding three Constitution and Wisdom saves, and one Intelligence and Charisma save.
- *[Nathair's mischief](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/nathairs-mischief)* from *Fizban’s Treasury of Dragons* has one of four randomly determined effects, with a 50% chance of forcing a Wisdom save and 25% chance of a Dexterity save. (The other effect does not allow a saving throw.) I have just counted it once for each save.

Because of those two spells, the total spell count here seems slightly lower than it ought to be. There may be other such spells which have a saving throw involved other than a single primary one, but there is no easy way to search for them. I believe this list is still pretty indicative of the frequency of saving throws in spells.

| Saving Throw | Official | % Official | Partnered | All | % All |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Strength | 17 | 7.87% | 2 | 19 | 8.19% |
| Dexterity | 66 | 30.56% | 1 | 67 | 28.88% |
| Constitution | 52 | 24.07% | 14 | 66 | 28.45% |
| Intelligence | 10 | 4.63% | 1 | 11 | 4.74% |
| Wisdom | 56 | 25.93% | 2 | 58 | 25.00% |
| Charisma | 15 | 6.95% | 0 | 11 | 4.74% |
| **Total spells** | **208** |  | **20** | **228** |  |

Note that some spells previously included as official are now noted as "partnered content" on D&D Beyond, specifically those from the two Critical Role books published by Wizards of the Coast. I'll also note that filtering for spells with any kind of save comes up with more spells than the method I used of filtering for each save separately, a discrepancy I've not yet solved. I also need to check if some spells are being counted twice where the Basic Rules version uses a different name (e.g. *Tasha’s hideous laughter* and *hideous laughter*). But I think above stats are still pretty representative.

For a list of official sources for spells, and how to find them on D&D Beyond, see this question: [What official books contain spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150765/what-official-books-contain-spells) (The list in the accepted answer is out of date, but the method for finding official books still works.)

Comment: BTW, here's a question specifically covering the topic of what books have spells: [What official books contain spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150765/what-official-books-contain-spells)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast it includes both Tasha’s and Xanathar’s; the UA spells mentioned are those which ended up in Fizban’s, I think without significant alteration, but there are a handful of spells in Strichaven which are not included. I’ll do an update.

Comment: _[Symbol](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol)_ contains multiple different saving throws, depending on the effect selected.

Comment: Great resource.  Question about the new update: "I've updated it again - it's now current as of **12/01/2024**."  Is that European date format?  If so, perhaps better listed with words as "January 12th", so we yanks don't read it as December 1st.

Comment: @Kirt that’s true - I just used the same format as before and didn’t think of this! I’ll change it. I feel bound to point out it’s not just a European format, but one used in most places  outside the US. I do think y/m/d is superior to either, though. ;)

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie Yes, I am aware - but "European format" seemed quicker than "most places but US, Canada, Belize, China, Japan, Korea, Iran."  I will admit that I assumed that 'McKenzie' was European - but I now see Melbourne in your profile.  My mistake.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie: I, an American sick of dealing with the ambiguity of dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy, tend to use dd MMM YYYY format when I'm not programming, e.g. 12 Jan 2024, as it removes all ambiguity (and people tend to read it more easily than ISO standard 2024-01-12, the only correct format when you have to store a date as a string for programmatic purposes) and doesn't make it much longer. So your replacement form that's essentially the same, but with the month fully spelled out, gets a +1 from me.

Answer (score 30):

According to [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/), the number of spells in the [SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf) that require saves on each attribute is:

|  | Attribute | # spells |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Strength | 4 |
| ⋆ | Dexterity | 32 |
| ⋆ | Constitution | 24 |
|  | Intelligence | 2 |
| ⋆ | Wisdom | 34 |
|  | Charisma | 12 |

But saving throws are required for many things that aren't spells, including non-spell monster abilities (a [medusa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/medusa)'s Petrifying Gaze, for example), traps, poisons, and environmental hazards. So I don't think optimizing based on spells alone is ideal.

Furthermore, spells don't appear with equal frequency, so just counting the number of spells that call for a given attribute's save is probably not going to yield much useful information.

Comment: Of note, almost all of the illusion spells require an Intelligence (Investigation) check to reveal the illusion, and they aren't counted on this list (most likely because they're not an automatic save, but rather an active check.) Still, might be worth adding to your answer if you see fit.

Comment: @LinoFrankCiaralli those aren't saving throws (which is what the question was about), and I was limiting my answer to information easily provided by the D&D Beyond beta spell search tool.

Comment: I understand, and I agree with your answer. That's why I added the last sentence, since it would be extra information that is tangentially connected. Like, if this was my answers, I'd simply add a sentence that says, "And in addition to the automatic saves above, there are many spells and effects which also have active checks against attributes in order to end their ongoing effects. For example: A grapple requires an active strength check, or illusion spells which usually require an active Intelligence check." - But again, add it if you see fit, it's your answer, and a good one at that.

Comment: Marq, you may want to update this now that Xanathar's Guide To Everything has been released: quite a few more Int save spells now.