# Typical Examples of Saving Throws for Player Characters?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw

Say I want to take the Resilient Feat and have more than one option for the ability score to raise:

> ### Resilient
>
> Choose one ability score. You gain the following benefits:
>
> - Increase the chosen ability score by 1, to a maximum of 20.
> - You gain proficiency in saving throws using the chosen ability.

I'd like to understand the types of scenarios that would typically require a Strength-based saving throw versus an Intelligence-based one, to identify the priority of each for my character.

**What are typical examples of a saving throw associated with each attribute?**
(e.g. "avoiding a trap is typically a DEX saving throw")

Note: The distribution of saving throws across attributes can be found [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98107/what-is-dd-5es-saving-throw-distribution-across-attributes).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The *Dungeon Masters Guide* has a table on p.238 which answers your question directly:

**Strength:** Opposing a force that would physically move or bind you

**Dexterity:** Dodging out of harm's way

**Constitution:** Enduring a disease, poison, or other hazard that saps vitality

**Intelligence:** Disbelieving certain illusions and resisting mental assaults that can be refuted with logic, sharp memory, or both

**Wisdom:** Resisting effects that charm, frighten, or otherwise assault your willpower

**Charisma:** Withstanding effects, such as possession, that would subsume your personality or hurl you to another plane of existence

Comment: I am not sure how much information from the DMG I am allowed to quote... I feel this is necessary to answer the question, but I guess the reference could suffice.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I wish this exact blurb would be included with the PHB to really clarify Chapter 7's section on saving throws.