# How do I calculate my passive Wisdom (Perception) check?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, skills

My 1st level Wizard has a Wisdom of 13 (modifier +1) and proficiency in Wisdom saving throws, but not proficiency in Perception. Does that mean my passive Wisdom (Perception) score equals 10+1 or 10+1+2 (adding my proficiency bonus).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and see the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you need more guidance.

Comment: Just a note: goodguy5 voted "unclear" originally before the comment stream, and the edits; the "close as dupe" was my gold "dupe close" thing in operation.   I am pretty sure it's a dupe.  Brandon, don't take the "close" as a bad thing, there are a lot of different ways to ask the same question.  Your question and the other one are now linked, so it's a win-win.

Answer (score 6):

## Proficiency in a Saving Throw is different from proficiency in a Skill

Each class gets a number of proficiencies.

For example, Wizards are proficient in both Intelligence and Wisdom [Saving Throws](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103384/typical-examples-of-saving-throws-for-player-characters) and would add their Proficiency Bonus to any Saving Throws made with those attributes.

Wizards also have access to a number of skills like Arcana, Medicine, and Religion.

Having proficiency in a Saving Throw **does not** grant proficiency in a skill using the same attribute.

That makes your Passive Perception 10+1 = 11.

So, if a Wizard has proficiency with Wisdom Saving Throws, but not the Wisdom (Perception) skill, then any Perception skill-checks would not gain the proficiency bonus.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I now understand hand to calculate passive perception and can finally finish up my caharcater.

Comment: @Brandon Hope you have great adventures!  :)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast same to you.